# NetBeans Platform - listen for changes to BeanNode<T>s in a PropertySheetView

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to intercept an event when a user makes a change to a property sheet (view).

I have tried adding `PropertyChangeListeners` and `NodeListeners` to the node, neither of which fires an event when the node is changed. Also, I tried adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `PropertySheetView` itself, but no dice.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PropertyChangeSupport` to your model (whatever object your Nodes are wrapping).

```
private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

// add interested listeners here
public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

// don't forget to remove them
public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}
```

Then when you change a model's value through the UI, you can fire a property change in the property's setter:

```
public void setMyValue(String myValue) {
    String oldValue = this.myValue;
    this.myValue = myValue;
    support.firePropertyChange("myValue", oldValue, this.myValue);
}
```

See the [NetBeans Nodes API](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html) tutorial for more details.  Also, you'll probably have better luck and quicker responses if you asked questions about the NetBeans Platform in the [NetBeans Platform Users](http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html) forum.